# Ww2 call of duty, can hear sound but no picture

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, call-of-duty-ww2

I just downloaded this game and it shows the beginning of the maker and stuff. Now after that the screen is black but I can hear the music in the background. Is it still downloading?

Comment: Where'd you get it from? Do you meet the system requirements?

Comment: I bought it at target brand new. Yes I checked the requirements and everything seems good. Like right now it’s on the main menu of the ps4 where it says “start” I can see where it looks like it’s still loading  but it’s just weird that I can hear the music of the game just the picture I cannot see

Comment: Can I delete it from the ps4 and re install it?

Comment: You can certainly try that (whether you bought it digitally or on disc).  I would also check all of your cabling to your display and make sure they are connected fully.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me too. The game was working ok for a few days then a black screen appears after the Activision/Sledgehammer intro.  I can hear music but no picture. I did a hard reset on the PS4 and it's seems to work. I hope this helps.